# summing the dice trials and histogram plot

Tags: python

I am stuck in a code in python which takes in number of dices and number of rolls and returns the sum of numbers obtained. It should also print the histogram of the sum. I am stuck in the first part of the code. Can someone help me fix this? Not sure where i am going wrong. Any help for the second part (returning histogram) would be helpful for me to learn it in python.

```
from random import choice

def roll(rolls,dice):
    d = []
    for _ in range(rolls):
        d[sum(choice(range(1,7)) for _ in range(dice))] += 1

return(d)
```

Comment: You might look at this book (its free) it uses Python, and a lot of dice examples, to teach Bayesian statistics.

Comment: @cjohnson318: There is no link in you comment.  It looks like you intended to put one there.

Comment: Derp. Thanks, here's the link: http://greenteapress.com/thinkbayes/index.html

Comment: Your `return` is outside your function

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here is that you can't arbitrarily index into an empty list:

```
l = []
l[13] += 1 # fails with IndexError
```

Instead, you could use a [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects), which is a special type of dictionary that doesn't mind if a key hasn't been used yet:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(int) # default to integer (0)
d[13] += 1 # works fine, adds 1 to the default
```

or [`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects), which is designed for cases like this ("provided to support convenient and rapid tallies") and provides extra handy functions (like `most_common(n)`, to get the `n` most common entries):

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter()
c[13] += 1
```

To manually use a standard `dict` to do this, just add a check:

```
d = {}
if 13 in d: # already there
    d[13] += 1 # increment
else: # not already there
    d[13] = 1 # create
```

Comment: thank you. I forgot to mention. it should be done without using inbuilt functions like defaultdict, counter and so on.. Just simple for loops to be used.

Comment: You could use the `setdefault()` method to do a similar thing, if `collections.defaultdict()` is not allowed.

Comment: In that case, you could do it with a standard `dict` and check for the keys - edited

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
from random import choice
import pylab

def roll( rolls, dice ):
s = list()
for d in range( dice ):
    for r in range( rolls ):
        s.append( choice( range(1,7) ) )
return s

s = roll( rolls, dice )

sum_of_rolls = sum( s )

# then to plot..
pylab.hist( s )
```

Comment: This wouldn't let you produce the histogram, you only get the sum total

Comment: Sorry, I skimmed recklessly.

Comment: thank you. I forgot to mention. it should be done without using inbuilt functions like defaultdict, counter and so on.. Just simple for loops to be used.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
import random

def rolls(N, r):  # N=number of dice. r=number of rolls
    myDie = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    answer = {}
    for _rolling in range(r):
        rolls = []
        for _die in range(N):
            rolls.append(random.choice(myDie))
        total = 0
        for roll in rolls:
            total += roll
        if total not in answer:
            answer[total] = 0
        answer[total] += 1
    return answer
```

Comment: Thanks. When i run this i get this output:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    rolls(2,2)
  File "C:\Python33\dice.py", line 8, in rolls
    rolls.append(random.choice(1,7))
TypeError: choice() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: @Rachel: fixed! Sorry about that