# Changing inbuilt functions for dice rolls program

Tags: python

I am writing a code in python for histogram plot of number of trials using given number of dices. I found a code in stack overflow and modified it which gives the result according to my requirement. Here is my modified code.

```
import random
from collections import defaultdict

def main(dice,rolls):
    result = roll(dice, rolls)
    maxH = 0
    for i in range(dice, dice * 6 + 1):
        if result[i] / rolls > maxH: maxH = result[i] / rolls
    for i in range(dice, dice * 6 + 1):
        print('{:2d}{:10d}{:8.2%} {}'.format(i, result[i], result[i] / rolls, '#' * int(result[i] / rolls / maxH * 40)))


def roll(dice,rolls):
    d = defaultdict(int)
    for _ in range(rolls):
        d[sum(random.randint(1, 7) for _ in range(dice))] += 1
    return d
```

However, i should implement this without using inbuilt functions like defaultdict, random.randint,.format. Is it possible to replace them but still get the desired output?I tried several ways but could not get them replaced.

Comment: Why are `range` and `print` allowed? They are also builtin functions only

Comment: Are you really required to generate random numbers with code you write yourself from scratch? This is completely non-trivial.

Comment: Didn't you just [ask this question less than an hour ago](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21312819/198633)? What's insufficient in the responses you received there (mine was one of them, and I'd be happy to update it if you leave a comment)?

Comment: I already put a standard `dict`-based `defaultdict` equivalent in my answer to the previous question. I find it hard to believe you are required to reimplement `random` - is it just `randint` you can't use? How about `randrange`?

Answer (score 0):

Do not try and get a random number without using `random`. It is FAR above and beyond what any homework assignment at this level would expect, and is a non-trivial problem even for professional programmers to generate a good PRNG. We can cut out `defaultdict` and `format` though.

```
import random

def roll(dice,rolls):
    d = {}
    i = 0
    while i < rolls: # to avoid the builtin range()
        result = sum((random.randint(1, 6) for _ in range(dice)))
        # or if you want to avoid the builtins sum() and range()
        #   result = 0
        #   dicerolled = 0
        #   while dicerolled < dice:
        #       result += random.randint(1,6)
        #       dicerolled += 1
        try: d[result] += 1
        except KeyError: d[result] = 1
        i += 1
    return d

def main(dice,rolls):
    results = roll(dice,rolls)
    MAXH = 60 # what's your hist scale
    maxH = max(results.values())
    # or if you want to avoid the builtin max() as well
    #   for count in result.values():
    #       if count/rolls > maxH: maxH = count
    SCALE = MAXH/maxH #this is your scale
    for theroll,count in sorted(results.items()):
        if len(str(theroll)) < 2: print(" ",end='')
        print(str(theroll) + " : " + "H"*int(count*SCALE))
```

We end up with a program that can avoid all builtins but the `random` module, `str()` and `int()` (which are both technically constructors anyway). The biggest question is: WHY!?!?!?!

Python is MADE for using and exploiting libraries, and the stdlib is Batteries Included for a reason! USE YOUR BUILTINS, USE YOUR IMPORTS, or code in a different language.